# how to access to the main data context in the datagrid binding?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, datagrid

I have a control which name is "Principal" and this control has a dataGrid.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IDVideo" Binding="{Binding IDVideo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Título" Binding="{Binding Titulo, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ucVideosDgdVideosTipoMultiValueConverter}">
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding ElementName="Principal" Path="DataContext.Generos"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duración" Binding="{Binding Duracion, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Año" Binding="{Binding Anyo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descripción" Binding="{Binding Descripcion, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want to use a multibinding to set the value of one of the columns (Genero). In the converter I see the first binding but the second, in which I want to send a property of the main control, I don't be able to do it.

How could I send the second binding to the converter?

Thanks.

Comment: try relativeSource Binding or staticresource binding instead of elementName binding

Comment: Could you please post the code of `ucVideosDgdVideosTipoMultiValueConverter`?

Comment: The code of the converter at the moment do nothing because I don't receive in the second element of the object[]values parameter the information that I need. Hoever the converter is executed.

Comment: @blindmeis: could you give an example of how I could use tue relative source?